# ReferenceError: document is not defined on document.querySelector addEventListener

Tags: referenceerror

Hi I am building a simple calculator. When I execute got a get the following error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

document.querySelector('loan-form').addEventListener('click', calculateResults)

document.querySelector('loan-form').addEventListener('click', calculateResults)
^
ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Could you share some details on how you're executing this? document might only be available if you're running this in a browser context. What do your files look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.